# How to filter ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT intent by file extension

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have code that launches a file picker by issuing a createChooser with an ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT intent.

Here is the code, which works:

```
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                intent.setType("*.*");
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose .xyz file"), RQS_OPEN_XYZ_FILE);
```

This opens a file picker that allows the user to select any type of file.

I would like to have the file picker limit the user's choices to only files that end in ".xyz".

If this were a "standard" file type, I could filter it by MIME type. For example, if I add a setType("media/jpeg"), only jpeg files will be able to be selected in the file picker. But, in this case, there is no MIME type that corresponds to ".xyz".

It was suggested to me that I try using a Data Path filter, but I have not been able to figure out how to implement that.

Is it possible to accomplish this? If so, how do I do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for us all but this is not possible.

Comment: I think the answer is here: https://vadzimv.dev/2021/01/01/android-pick-file.html